# Random number not repeating same value in a row

Tags: c#, random

I have the following random number gen:

```
val = rnd.Next(1, 4)+1;
```

I have looked at similar questions on the site and I believe the +1 is meant to prevent getting the same number in a row.

I want the sequence to be random, but I do not want the same value twice in a row. For example:

`1,1,2,2,3,4` would be wrong but `1,2,1,2,3,4,3` would meet my needs.

I tried the following but it doesn't solve my issue:

```
void numLogic()
{
  System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
  int val;
  int oldval = val;
  val = rnd.Next(1, 4)+1;
  while (oldval == val)
  {
    val = rnd.Next(1, 4) + 1;
  }
}
```

Note that `numLogic()` is called successfully after each number is generated by an object collision in unity. The problem is not with the game object, this works fine. I just don't want two number the same in a row.

Comment: The only thing the +1 does is make your range 2-4 instead of 1-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int val;
 int oldval = val;
```

This sets oldval = 0;

You would need to save your val outside the function

```
static int lastVal;
void numLogic()
{   
  var val = rnd.Next(1, 4)+1;
  while (lastVal== val)
        {
            val = rnd.Next(1, 4) + 1;
        }
        lastval = val;
 }
```

Comment: it's a little outdated, but this is a perfect example of a `do...while` use case.

Answer (score 1):

The `+1` after `rnd.Next(1,4)` is not necessary at all. Just change to bounds to `rnd.Next(2,5)` to archieve the same. (But I guess you don't want this?)

The problem with you function is: you only generate one number. `oldval` should be a variable outside of your function and store the value of the last function call. Something like:

```
int oldrnd = 0;
int nextRandom() {
    int val = rnd.Next(1,4);
    while(oldrnd == val) val = rnd.Next(1,4);
    oldrnd = val;
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 is NOT to prevent getting the same number in a row.
It's preventing to get zero (by shifting range by one).

```
using System;
class Program
    {
        static void numLogic()
    {
      int val;
      int oldval ;//= val;
      Random rnd = new Random();
      val = rnd.Next(1, 4)+1;
      oldval=val;
      int numberOfNumbers = 7;
      int i=0;
      while (i<numberOfNumbers)
            {
                val = rnd.Next(1, 4) + 1;
                if(oldval==val)continue;
                oldval=val;
                Console.Write("{0} ",val);
                i++;
            }
     }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            numLogic();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a loop on rnd.next to avoid the problem: after initial random(1,4), loop on val=random(1,3) and add 1 to val when val>=oldval.

```
System.Random rnd = new System.Random();
List<int> nums = new List<int>() ;
int ListCount = 10 ; // expected length of the sequence
int val = rnd.Next(1, 4)+1;
nums.Add(val)        
for (int i=1;i<ListCount;i++)  
  nums.Add((val=rnd.Next(1,3)+1)<nums[i-1] ? val : val+1) ;
```